# Solve the equation. e and natural logs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$$e^x − 6e^{-x} − 1 = 0$$

No idea how to solve this. If someone could show me the first one or two steps to push me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Have you heard of hidden quadratics? Try multiplying with $e^x$ and see if you can use that to solve it by setting $u=e^x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $e^x = a$

$$ a - \frac{6}{a} - 1 = 0$$

$$ a^2 - a-6 = 0$$

$$ a = 3 \ or \ -2 $$

$$ e^x = 3$$

Edit: for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Can you find the value of x now?
Hint: take $\ln$ of both sides.

Comment: Any particular reason $e^x$ _can't_ be $-2$? (imaginary roots)

Comment: @ColeJohnson, $\log x$ is undefined for $x \leq 0$ so a solution exists only for $e^x = 3$

Comment: @ColeJohnson no reason, but in the contexts in which one would be asked to solve this equation, it's often implicit that the domain of solution is taken to be the real numbers.

Comment: @DavidZ, I suppose one should really add "for $ x \in \mathbb{R}$" to the answer to make it absolutely clear.

Answer (score 6):

HINT : Multiply the both sides by $e^x$ to get
$$(e^x)^2-6-e^x=0.$$
Now, let $e^x=t$.

Answer (score 6):

You can rewrite this as

$$(e^x)^2-6-e^x=0$$

$$(e^x+2)(e^x-3)=0$$

I'll let you take it from here

Answer (score 4):

HINT: multiply both sides by $e^x$ to turn it into a quadratic equation in $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$e^x − 6e^{-x} − 1 = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{-x}(e^x-3)(e^x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{-x}=0\vee(e^x-3)=0\vee(e^x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{-x}=0\vee(e^x-3)=0\vee(e^x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$error\vee e^x=3\vee e^x=-2$$